# Accessing hash attribute the same way as accessing an object attribute

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a ruby hash, say

```
h={name: "john", age: "23"}
```

It is not an object, just a hash created from an object. I want to access its values with the method attribute as I access an object. i.e.:

```
h.name => "john"
h.age  => 23
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `h[name] or h[age]`?

Comment: In a rabl template, where i just want to render a hash, not an object.

Comment: If it is a hash, then it is an object.

Comment: I just check rabl doc they also recommend openstruct.
https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Rendering-hash-objects-in-rabl

Comment: I agree with squiguy, h[:name] or h[:age] is what you have.  Why put in all that overhead to make a method out of it?

Comment: @kikuchiyo this is why i need to do it.

github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Rendering-hash-objects-in-rabl

Comment: @sovanlandy - I see.  This may also be of use to you:  https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Tips-and-tricks.

Answer (score 9):

In your case it will be handy to use [openstruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)

```
require 'ostruct'

h = OpenStruct.new(name: "john", age: "23")

h.name #=> "john"
h.age  #=> 23
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
item = Struct.new(:id, :name)
item.new(1, 'Name')
```